# object.attr('value') returns property value instead of attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code. When I use firebug to check discountInput, it says: Object [input property value ="77" attribute value="75"]

However, "originalAmount" is 77 and so is "amount". How do I get the attribute value? I want to use it because I need to know what was originally in the input field before it was changed. I am using jquery 1.6.2 for this.

```
var cell = $(this);
var discountInput = $("input[name=discount]", cell);
var originalAmount = discountInput.attr('value');
var amount = discountInput.val();
```

Comment: Why have you use ",cell" in var discountInput = $("input[name=discount]", cell);

Comment: @NikhilBatra it's like `cell.find("input[name=discount]")`

Comment: @NikhilBatra so that the correct input from within the cell is selected.  Probably not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `defaultValue` property on `discountInput`.

```
var cell = $(this);
var discountInput = $("input[name=discount]", cell);
var originalAmount = discountInput[0].defaultValue;
var amount = discountInput.val();
```

Comment: Yes that worked. It seems to be something to do with my jquery version. I changed it to another version and it was ok. I am going to use your method as it works in both versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var amount  = $('input[name="discount"]', this).attr("value");
```